# list of colors between mulitiple colors in python

Tags: python, colors, range

For my project, I need to show the value of a variable from min to max using a user-defined number of colors. this user-defined variable(numberOfLevels) is a multiplication of 5 (5,10,15,20,25,...). though, it is not that easy because the final color palette is a range of colors between multiple colors. So I have a palette of 5 initial colors and I want to convert it to a palette with 40 colors, where colors are equally divided across 5 initial colors.

here's an example of the initial color palette

```
paletteList = [
[Color("#ff0000"),
Color("#ff8000"),
Color("#ffff00"),
Color("#00ffff"),
Color("#0000ff")],
]
```

and here's the formula I have crafted to make the final color palette

```
numberOfLevels = 40
sizeOfBucket = int(numberOfLevels / 5)

for x in range(0, len(paletteList[0])-1 ):
    templist = list(paletteList[0][x].range_to(paletteList[0][x+1],sizeOfBucket+1))
    for m in templist:
    res.append(m)
```

to remove repeated colors

```
for m in res:
    if m not in templist:
           templist.append(m)
```

the problem with this code is that it shows 36 colors while I asked of 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `sizeOfBucket+1` which is 8+1 = 9 and you are running your `range()` from 0 to 5-1 which means range(0, 4) which will run 4 times so you have 9*4 = 36 points.

Instead what you should do is the following to get 40 colors: Run the `range` as `range(0, len(paletteList[0]))` which means `range(0, 5)` (0, 1, 2, 3, 4 so in total 5 times) and the `range_to` should use `sizeOfBucket` which is 8. So now you will have 8*5=40 colors.

```
numberOfLevels = 40
sizeOfBucket = int(numberOfLevels / 4)

for x in range(0, len(paletteList[0])-1 ):
    templist = list(paletteList[0][x].range_to(paletteList[0][x+1],sizeOfBucket))
    for m in templist:
        res.append(m)
```

**Edit 2**

```
numberOfLevels = 40
sizeOfBucket = int(numberOfLevels / 4)

for x in range(0, len(paletteList[0])-1):
    if 0<x<len(paletteList[0])-2:
        templist = list(paletteList[0][x].range_to(paletteList[0][x+1],sizeOfBucket+1))
    else:
        templist = list(paletteList[0][x].range_to(paletteList[0][x+1],sizeOfBucket))
    for m in templist:
        res.append(m)
```

Comment: that way I get "list index out of range" cuz for last loop in "paletteList[0][x+1]" I ask for 5 index with doesn't exist .

Comment: but then how do you expect 40? can you show me the math?

Comment: what way do you suggest to create 40 colors between 5 colors without repetition?

Comment: it gives me 42. but still way better than my code. do you know why it gives two  extra colors?

Comment: did you remove the duplicates? how do you import Color